# How to initialize STL vector of pointers from array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

I need to initialize a std::vector from an array double*. Here is the current code:

```
class MyClass {
...
    std::vector<double*> myVector;

    void MyClass(double* vectorData, size_t dataCount) {
        myVector(dataCount, NULL);
        for (unsigned int ii = 0; ii < dataCount; ++ii) {
            myVector.push_back(vectorData + ii );
        }
        ...
    }     
...
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a good way to replace that for loop with a vector constructor or a call like myVector.fillWithPointers( myData, dataCount ).

I know that I can write my own function to do this, but I'm wondering if there is a built-in way to do it. And yes, I've left out exception handling and data checking for readability here.

Comment: `myVector.resize(dataCount); std::iota(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), vectorData);`.

Comment: Also, constructors must have no return type. Also, `myVector(dataCount, NULL)` is not a valid piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want this (fixes all other compilation problems in your code as well):

```
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
  std::vector<double*> myVector;

public:
  MyClass(double* vectorData, size_t dataCount)
    : myVector(dataCount)
  {
    std::iota(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), vectorData);
  }

  void DebugShowVectors()
  {
    for (double *d : myVector)
      std::cout << *d << "\n";
  }
};

int main()
{
  double data[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3 };    
  MyClass instance(data, sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]));
  instance.DebugShowVectors();
}
```

But I'm not sure if storing pointers to `double`s in the vector instead of the `double`s themselves is really a good idea in first place.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that's definitely better

Comment: The use of pointers is needed for reasons outside the scope of the question, but I was unaware of the iota() function, which gives me exactly what I wanted. Thanks!